# Access public pictures without an access token?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, access-token

I created a php module for Drupal that pulls a public album and display pictures inside it. I discovered that the module suddenly stopped working. I googled and looks like even a public album requires an access token now. I see access token field on https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=10150146071791729

In this case, how do I fix this problem? It looks like even offline_access is gone now.

Do I must ask users to accept a certain permission? What permission? It's a public pictures.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, found an answer.

You need to create an app and get an app id and a secret key.

Once you have those two, download Facebook PHP SDK on https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk.

**Sample Code:**

```
require_once "facebook.php";

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'appid',
  'secret' => 'securet',
));

$token = $facebook->getAccessToken();

$json = file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/293849234?access_token=".$token);
```

Comment: You can generate the App Access token as `App_ID|App_Secret` also, so you will not require the SDK.