# Getting page photos with Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using Facebook Graph API here: http://crackit.seegermattijs.be/wedstrijd.html I'm trying to get access with the following url: https://graph.facebook.com/10150146071791729/photos

This was working for 2 weeks but all of a sudden I always get following error

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "An access token is required to request this resource.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 104
   }
}
```

Is there anyone who can figure this out?

Kind regards

Seeger

Comment: duplicated: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16406501/access-public-pictures-without-an-access-token

Comment: Check if you are having valid access token to access it or not.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ....

```
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=10150146071791729%2Fphotos
```

I'm using 'Graph API Explorer', that's no problem.

"message": "An access token is required to request this resource."

This message means "You're not logged in with Facebook"

Answer (score -1):

You need to renew your Access Token.

1. Ensure that you are an Admin of the Facebook Page.
2. go to :
   http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer
3. In the API Navigator, you can see "/me" will bring up the basic information of yourself.
4. Try typing in "/me/accounts" to see if you can see anything. It should give you an error.
5. Click on "Get Access Token"
6. a window will pop-up. Navigate to "Extended Permissions"
7. Select "manage_pages"
8. Click "Get Access Token"
9. Now try "/me/accounts" again. You should see a list of Groups inside the viewing window.
10. Select the Page you want, and click on the "id" field
11. Next, on the left window, you can see "Node:  " and a + sign. Click on the + sign to see what are the options you have.
12. Click on the + sign and scroll down to "connections" and select "Albums"
13. The child-level, select "Photos"
14. The "Photos" child-level, select "source"
15. Now click "Submit" on the right hand side. You will see a JSON returned with the url of all the photos in your Facebook Page.
16. Copy the URL - https://graph.facebook.com/?fields=albums.fields(photos.fields(source)) and plug it into your browser. You should see a JSON of all your photos.